# Getting the shipping method code in transactional emails

Tags: shipping-methods, transactional-mail, variables

We’re currently calling the variable "{{var shippingMethod}}” but it’s  retrieving the description “fedex_STANDARD_OVERNIGHT”.

Is there a way to grab the code in place of the description.

For the one above it would just be **FG** (Example: FG).

I figure I could manually change this in the database but that's probably not the preferred method.

Should i assign/map it the value i'm looking for?? Do i need to edit or create a custom phtml file to include a block with custom variables?

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Not sure I follow 100%, but I'll take a shot at it.</strike>

<strike>`{{var shippingMethod}}` is not a standard variable on sales email templates, so it must be something you already inject as custom.</strike>

Default templates in Magento will use `{{var order.shipping_description}}`, and you're saying that's not what you want?

Note that in a proper sales transactional email context you will have the `order` object at your disposal, so anything off the order model is available. Try these to explore your options:

**Shipping Method + Carrier Code**

```
{{var order.getShippingMethod()}}
```

**Shipping Method Code**

```
{{var order.getShippingMethod(1).getMethod()}}
```

**Shipping Carrier Code**

```
{{var order.getShippingMethod(1).getCarrierCode()}}
```

**Shipping Carrier Name**

```
{{var order.getShippingCarrier().getConfigData('title')}}
```

Where the 2nd option is probably the one you're looking for.

Comment: I got it from this extensive list found here: https://gist.github.com/tiagones/e2f3f822515e2fe0d23d

Comment: I see, OK. I scanned the core code myself and believe that it is only used here: `Mage_Checkout_Helper_Data::sendPaymentFailedEmail`; I could be wrong, but anyway, let me know if any of the above 3 will work in your case. I am basing my answer on a context like this one: `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail`.

Comment: The top two displayed the same thing, in my case it was: fedex_STANDARD_OVERNIGHT fedex_STANDARD_OVERNIGHT. Testing the third code right now.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of those seemed to work. What was the 1 for in the second code.

Comment: The "1" acts as a flag to return the method as an object so we can chain another call; see `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::getShippingMethod($asObject = false)`. Also, I was mistaken on the first example: it _does_ render the carrier code + method code together. I've updated my answer, try the new second option.

Comment: I get it, if there's a 1 it's equivalent to true in the Mage_Sales_Model_Order::getShippingMethod(asObject = false). Thanks for helping me understand that.